# Multiple iPhone App Versions for Different Countries

Tags: iphone, multiple-versions, countries

I created an app and it is currently live in the app store for all countries.  I would like to roll out a different version of my app for the UK, the only difference being the cities users see.  Is it possible to do this ?  What is the procedure for doing this when you already have an app live in the app store for all countries ?  Is this not a good way to go ?  I could simply show all cities in one version of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the location via CoreLocation and show the corresponding dataset when you detect that you're inside UK, but that won't work if you're in the basement with no WiFi nearby (or in the subway, for that matter). If it's just for convenience this might be the way to go. Don't rely on it to work, CoreLocation can be fooled on jailbroken devices and in environments with no GPS and no/poor WiFi reception.

You could also roll a second version (a new target in Xcode) of your app with a different app ID that specifically targets the UK and use e.g. defines or target membership of datafiles so that different version has the right dataset. If I understood you correctly that would be a "limited" version in that it wouldn't have the full dataset of your existing app, so if it's a paid app the UK version should be cheaper as it has less functionality (but that's actually up to you as long as Apple doesn't nag).

Answer (score 0):

You could add all cities to your app and with a Country picker, choose by default the country the user's IP address is from.